# What is happening when Xdebug stops at the first line of a set of functions from in the same file?

Tags: php, xdebug

When doing a single-step in xdebug on a PHP application there are times when each step is just the first line of the functions (function signatures text) defined in the file.  I'm guessing this is the execution of loading the function code in memory to be executed when the function is called.  Is that correct or not?

Comment: Do you use Netbeans?

Comment: IDE is PHPStorm.